# Can an Android device be remotely factory reset using any email ID on the device?

Tags: factory-reset, gmail, remote-wipe

We had created a common ID for the college group and I think someone remotely wiped my phone. Is it possible to do it with the secondary account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with Google's [find my device](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=androidconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&ltmpl=findmydevice&rart=ANgoxccUjvqMitYVqvjY5rF4xOTKuywou-mAlDvhRFkORF5IK9QzIaM9QEzzI0FIf2Bq57guqUptQBpm91LaGYKmlyLeIciisw&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) you can locate, lock, and ERASE, the phone. So anyone who has access to the accounts connected to your phone is able to erase all your data.
It's made for cases of lost phones where you want to stop the thief from accessing your data.
This feature is automatically enabled on most devices.

All the person would have to do in order to erase all your data, would be going to [find my device](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=androidconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fandroid%2Ffind&ltmpl=findmydevice&rart=ANgoxccUjvqMitYVqvjY5rF4xOTKuywou-mAlDvhRFkORF5IK9QzIaM9QEzzI0FIf2Bq57guqUptQBpm91LaGYKmlyLeIciisw&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) page, put in the joint email address and password, and press erase and confirm. As simple as that.

It doesn't make a difference if this account is the primary one, or a secondary account.

In the future don't add any accounts to the phone, that others have access to.

Comment: I'm surprised it is that way. I thought only the primary account(the one I use on the Play Store) had that privileges. Any way to find out who did this?

Comment: The only thing you might be able to see, is which email address was used to wipe your phone, but being that multiple people are using the same account it's most probably impossible to see who did it.

Comment: @Yashbhatt, if there is such a thing as ' primary account' it probably good by the first account added to the phone and not the one used in play store. All features are available in all accounts including find my device and erase. Google should definitely warn of this, as I've seen many people share accounts

Comment: Exactly. Any way of seeing the IP address of the device which was used to perform the reset?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if that's possible :( unless you contact Google support, they might tell you. Or maybe post a new question with a link to here. In the mean time, if I answered your original question correctly, feel free to mark it as such (the "√" next to the answer) so that others know this was "solved". Again sorry this happened to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Google Support said nothing can be done about it.