# Gmail on android - notifications for multiple users using the same account?

Tags: gmail, notifications

I have a Gmail account which accessed by multiple people. Sometimes it happens that we receive an e-mail and one of us doesn't get notified.

I'm guessing this is happening because when the e-mail arrives, if one of us gets a notification before the others and reads it too soon, then Gmail marks it read and doesn't notify other devices.

The only workaround I can think of is setting up an e-mail forward for all of us and then just disabling the notifications from the shared account.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Is this really an ANDROID problem, or merely a misapplication of Gmail to serve many people? To extrapolate, would this be an ANDROID problem if the singular account served 5 THOUSAND people, or even just 2? This is a misused Gmail problem. Please investigate how to configure THAT to satisfy your application scenario .

Comment: Don't have a good suggestion on this issue. Just wanted to mention that when you have a few people in the same account, you might wanna watch out for [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186152/241679)

Comment: @wbogacz nope. That's why I originally asked this on superuser but it was migrated here. I just mentioned android to give full details of what we are using.

Comment: @Abochur I'm aware of that. These accounts are actually "gmail for business" accounts used by my institute and they have disabled that. So you can't remotely install apps or do anything with your device with access to the account