# Turn off Samsung account Notifications

Tags: samsung, notifications, multiple-devices

In my company we recently decided to put all the company phone on one Samsung account. So if an employee loses there phone or forget there passcode we can help him. The only issue every time we add a new phone to the account everyone gets a notification. Is there a way to stop this and let only one phone get the notification?

Comment: I dont think so.  There is a duplicate [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189844/gmail-on-android-notifications-for-multiple-users-using-the-same-account).  There is another one on another site perhaps.  I cant find it.

Comment: I would suggest that the concept of the account is being abused, especially if this notification is a problem.  Are you adding multiple phones every day ?

Comment: Just this week because we are getting all the company phones onto the Samsung accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look around and its possible that one of these settings may help you.  I couldn't find desriptions for all of them, so it's trial and error.

- Goto Settings
- Scroll Down and select `Apps`
- In Search field type in `play service`
- There are probably two `Google Play Services`
- For each press `Notifications`
- Scroll Down and press on `Notification Categories`
- It will look like the image below
- Try turning off `Devices` and `Devices with your account`

[image]

Comment: This for Samsung accounts also?